# How to match URLs with .htaccess

Tags: php, javascript, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I haven't really ever made much use of the .htaccess file but I would like to know how I could match a link like:
http://localhost/test/pages/abc.php
to something like:
http://localhost/test/abc

I would like to take out the extension of the file as well as match the url. Not redirect but match the urls.

Is there any way to do this?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it, first it removes the .php extension, then strips pages/ from the url.

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^pages/(.+)$ http://www.yourblog.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```